# Rolling apply to subset of a vector

Tags: r, vector, subset, apply

I want to apply a function to progressive subsets of a vector in R. I have looked at what i could find, and the apply and friends aren't quite there, and rollapply does not work on straight vectors, only zoo/ts objects.

```
vapply <- function(x, n, FUN=sd) {
    v <- c(rep(NA, length(x)))
    for (i in n:length(x) ) {  
        v[i] <- FUN(x[(i-n+1):i])
    }
    return(v)
}
```

Is there something built in that is equivalent? Is there a better way to do it? I am trying to avoid dependencies on 3rd party libraries as I the code needs to be standalone for distribution.

Comment: Can you give us some data (and desired result) to play with?

Comment: I suggest you don't call it `vapply`, since this is already a widely-used function name (fast vector apply).

Comment: This is a minor point, but I believe `rollapply` does 'work' just fine on an atomic vector, it just converts it to a `zoo` object first. So that still runs afoul of your requirement to avoid dependencies.

Comment: A comment on your desired "standalone" condition:  Anyone who is going to use your R code (or package) that you're distributing is not going to have a problem with installing any package available at CRAN. But if you're really that worried, just include the required libraries with your distribution -- built into your package, or as part of your zip/tarball/whatever distro.

Comment: joran i had problems with something equivalent to this rollapply(1:100, width=10, FUN=sd). Carl, no it isn't a real showstopper, but I can't assume it will be used on a machine with a net connection and would prefer to avoid maintaining the dependancy for such a relatively trivial thing. Thank you all for stopping by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your choice of function name, I just HAD to make a version that actually uses `vapply` internally :)
...it turns out to be about 50% faster in the example below. But that of course depends a lot on how much work is done in FUN...

```
# Your original version - renamed...
slideapply.org <- function(x, n, FUN=sd) {
    v <- c(rep(NA, length(x)))
    for (i in n:length(x) ) {  
        v[i] <- FUN(x[(i-n+1):i])
    }
    return(v)
}

slideapply <- function(x, n, FUN=sd, result=numeric(1)) {
    stopifnot(length(x) >= n) 
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    nm1 <- n-1L
    y <- vapply(n:length(x), function(i) FUN(x[(i-nm1):i]), result)

    c(rep(NA, nm1), y) # Why do you want NA in the first entries?
}

x <- 1:2e5+0 # A double vector...
system.time( a <- slideapply.org(x, 50, sum) )  # 1.25 seconds
system.time( b <- slideapply(x, 50, sum) )      # 0.80 seconds
identical(a, b) # TRUE
```

Comment: very cool, thank you! I wanted the extra NA's so i could cbind it to an existing dataframe